# freemarker - access settings variable in template

Tags: freemarker

Is it possible to access a settings variable within a template?

**Setting:**

```
<#setting locale="${bean.locale}">
```

How can I use `locale` without reusing `${bean.locale}` within the template to avoid duplicate code, especially if its a deeper hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locale is a Special Variable, and can be access like this : `${.locale}`.

See the [freemarker documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_specvar.html)

Comment: Thank you, partly what I searched for. `${.locale}` seems to be a String. But I would prefer the locale instance to use in function calls.

Comment: Then you still have to put it into the data-model. However, calling `#setting` should be unnecessary, as the locale FreeMarker setting should be already set before calling the template. So there's no duplicate code in templates then.